# Using @Any annotation in legacy database where some of the discriminator values don't reference entities

Tags: hibernate

I have a legacy database with a table containing 2 columns, call them "TYPE" and "ID", that will refer to other entities. The problem is that only a subset of the TYPE values will refer to other entities. For example:

- TYPE = 0 - "none" - no entity
- TYPE = 2 - "a calculator" - ID is id of a Calculator entity
- TYPE = 5 - "pay value" - no entity
- TYPE = 6 - "a series" - ID is the id of a Series Entity

I've seen that @Any and @AnyMetaDef can be used to map a "TYPE" column and "ID" to a polymorphic entity but what about the "TYPE" values that don't map to entities?

Is there a best practice for how to deal with this situation?

- I wondered if targetEntity of Void.class can be safely used for values 0 and 5, if this would have hibernate return null in those cases.
- This doesn't let me distinguish between the None and PayValue cases. Is it possible to get hibernate to return a singleton object of type None and PayValue so that an instanceof test can be performed or is it allowed to just read the TYPE column as a normal persistant field?

Thanks.